# File extension case sensitivity on CentOS

Tags: image, apache, centos, case-sensitive

I'm using CentOS. There are >10M images in one of my folders, which are furthur grouped into subdirectories.

The issue is that some of my images are named as abc.jpg and others are named as xyz.JPG. So, when i try to access xyz.jpg, it says "File not found" as the extension is case-sensitive.

Is there any way to rename all JPG to jpg, or a httpd config which works around this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might be looking for the `rename` utility. I believe it's in most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `rename` you can do in `bash`:

```
for f in *.JPG; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}.jpg"; done
```